# How to tell if a task is running or dead in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am running a awk script in Ubuntu terminal. The script works for relatively small size file. So I tried it on a big file and it has been a long time and is still running.

I used top and this is what i got and the %MEM is changing from time to time.

```
PID USER    PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
2263 user   20   0 15.1g  12g  372 D   17 90.1   3:56.43 awko
```

I dont really know if it's dead or should I keep waiting? How can I tell it?

Comment: if it was dead, it would not be using 17% CPU, dont you think? It would not even be in TOP.

Comment: 12G RES is **huge**, what are the machine specs?

Comment: Memory: 14.1 GiB and Intel® Core™ i7-2760QM CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8

Comment: Without knowing what your awk script is doing the only answer that can be offered for this question is that it is using most of the memory of the machine. That it works for small inputs but not large is usually indicative of a program that is written with exponential time complexity which means you need a better algorithm. This question would also be improved if you said what large and small input sizes are.